# How do I bind datagrid column value to a textbox outside my datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So what im trying to do is have the values in my datagrid link with my textboxes outside of the datagrid so that if i change the value of the "rate" inside the data grid the price will adjust the FT AMNT price dynamically according to change i made inside the datagrid. I have posted a picture of the data grid and textboxes. If more information is required please let me know. Thank you!

**XAML CODE**

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgPcs" Header="PCS" Width="40" 
Binding="{Binding pieces}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgCode" Header="CODE" Width="50"  
Binding="{Binding code}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgDescr" Header="DESCRIPTION OF 
ARTICLES" Width="180" Binding="{Binding item_description}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgWt" Header="WT" Width="50" 
Binding="{Binding weight}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgRate" Header="RATE" Width="50" 
Binding="{Binding rate, StringFormat='C'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgDiscount" Header="DISCOUNT" 
Width="70" Binding="{Binding discount,StringFormat='C'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgAmt" Header="AMOUNT" Width="70" 
Binding="{Binding amount,StringFormat='C'}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="ACTION">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

<GroupBox Margin="788,382,19,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
RenderTransformOrigin="0.268,0.174" Width="230" Header="TOTAL" 
Height="auto">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="FRT AMNT: " Margin="9,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtFreightAmt" Width="100" Text="{Binding 
freightAmt,StringFormat='C'}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="ACCESSORIAL: "/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtAccess" Width="100" Text="{Binding 
accessorial,StringFormat='C'}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="COD FEE: " Margin="14,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtCodFee" Width="100" Text="{Binding 
codFee,StringFormat='C'}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="FRT DISC: " Margin="13,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtFrtDisc" Width="100" Text="{Binding 
freightDisc,StringFormat='C'}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="NET FRT: " Margin="15,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtNetFrt" Width="100" Text="{Binding 
freightNet,StringFormat='C'}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="BILL AMNT: " Margin="8,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBillAmnt" Width="100" Text="{Binding 
billAmount,StringFormat='C'}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
```

**Code for bound properties**

```
public List<Bills> GetBillData(string billId, int? otherId)
    {
        OdbcConnection con = GetConnection();
        DataTable dt;
        List<Bills> Bill = new List<Bills>();
        try
        {
            //string spName = "dbo.edi_getCorrectedBill";
            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            OdbcCommand sqlCmd = new OdbcCommand("{call dbo.edi_getCorrectedBill(?,?)}", con);
            da.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billId", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = billId.ToString().Trim();
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otherId", OdbcType.Int).Value = otherId;

            dt = new DataTable();
            sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Bills b = new Bills();
                    b.billNum = dr["bill_num"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.shipperID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Shipper_ID"]);
                    b.shipperName = dr["Shipper_name"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.shipperAddr1 = dr["Shipper_addr1"].ToString().Trim();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["shprAddr2"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.shprAddr2 = dr["shprAddr2"].ToString().Trim();

                    b.shipperCity = dr["Shipper_city"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.shipperState = dr["Shipper_state"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.shipperZip = dr["Shipper_zip"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.sPhone = dr["S_phone"].ToString().Trim();

                    b.consignID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Consign_ID"]);
                    b.consignName = dr["Consign_name"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.consignAddr1 = dr["Consign_addr1"].ToString().Trim();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["cneeAddr2"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.cneeAddr2 = dr["cneeAddr2"].ToString().Trim();

                    b.consignCity = dr["Consign_city"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.consignState = dr["Consign_state"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.consignZip = dr["Consign_zip"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.cPhone = dr["C_phone"].ToString().Trim();

                    b.otherID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Other_ID"]);
                    b.billName = dr["Bill_name"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.billAddr1 = dr["Bill_addr1"].ToString().Trim();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["billAddr2"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.billAddr2 = dr["billAddr2"].ToString().Trim();

                    b.billCity = dr["Bill_city"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.billState = dr["Bill_state"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.billZip = dr["Bill_zip"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.shipDate = dr["ship_date"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.org = dr["Org"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.dest = dr["Dest"].ToString().Trim();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Shipper_ref"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.shipperRef = dr["Shipper_ref"].ToString().Trim();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Consign_ref"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.cneeRef = dr["Consign_ref"].ToString().Trim();

                    b.term = dr["Term"].ToString().Trim();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Shrink_Wrap"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.shrinkWrap = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Shrink_Wrap"]);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Re_Weight_Class"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.reWt = dr["Re_Weight_Class"].ToString().Trim();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Agent_Pro"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.BYD = dr["Agent_Pro"].ToString().Trim();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["fuel_sc"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.fuelSC = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["fuel_sc"]);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["fuel_sc_percent"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.fuelScPercent = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["fuel_sc_percent"]);

                    b.accessorial = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["accessorial"]);
                    b.fccod = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Fccod"]);
                    b.codFee = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["cod_fee"]);
                    b.freightDisc = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["freight_disc"]);
                    b.freightAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["freight_amt"]);
                    b.billAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["bill_amount"]);
                    b.freightNet = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["freight_net"]);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Status"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.status = dr["Status"].ToString().Trim();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["description"].ToString().Trim()))
                        b.description = dr["description"].ToString().Trim();

                    Bill.Add(b);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection(con);
        }
        return Bill;
    }

    public List<BillItems> GetBillItemData(string billId)
    {
        OdbcConnection con = GetConnection();
        DataTable dt;
        List<BillItems> BillItem = new List<BillItems>();
        try
        {
            //string spName = "dbo.edi_getCorrectedBill";
            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            OdbcCommand sqlCmd = new OdbcCommand("{call dbo.edi_getCorrectedBillItems(?)}", con);
            da.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billId", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = billId.ToString().Trim();

            dt = new DataTable();
            sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    BillItems b = new BillItems();

                    b.pieces = Convert.ToInt32(dr["pieces"]);
                    b.code = dr["Code"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.item_description = dr["Description"].ToString().Trim();
                    b.weight = Convert.ToInt32(dr["weight"]);
                    b.rate = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["rate"]);
                    b.discount = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["discount"]);
                    b.amount = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["amount"]);
                    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["shprAddr2"].ToString().Trim()))
                    //    b.shprAddr2 = dr["shprAddr2"].ToString().Trim();
                    BillItem.Add(b);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection(con);
        }
        return BillItem;
    }
```

**Datagrid and total textboxes**

[image]

Comment: Are both the datagrid columns and the textboxes bound to the same properties in your viewmodel?

Comment: No they have different properties

Comment: You should edit your post to include the textbox's xaml and the code for all of the bound properties.

Comment: Also, are you trying to update the values on the click event of your Update Bill button or are you trying to update the values as soon as a change is made in your datagrid column/textbox?

Comment: Provide the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your viewmodel too.

Comment: @sudsy1002 im trying to update the values of the textboxes as soon as the datagrid column change has been made.. I think i should be using something like UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

Comment: You will need to update the values in your code based on a [DataGrid event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx#Events). From your event you can change the value in code. You will probably need UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in your xaml as you guessed in order to reflect the changed value in code.

Comment: if you are using Collection to store list of View models use CollectionChanged event to get Total .

Comment: @sudsy1002  Can you guys please show me a small example of code just to start me off? anything would help. Thanks.